# How to filter rowData by year using lodash in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to filter the rowData by year for example `2019`.
Then it display data have `2019`
here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
rowData = [
      {
        'machineCode': 'PEWDIEPIE001',
        'assetCode': 'LOCAL1',
        'date': '2019-03-02 09:02:00'
      },
      {
        'machineCode': 'PEWDIEPIE002',
        'assetCode': 'LOCAL1',
        'date': '2019-09-02 09:02:00'
      },
      {
        'machineCode': 'PEWDIEPIE001',
        'assetCode': 'LOCAL1',
        'date': '2019-10-02 09:02:00'
      },
      {
        'machineCode': 'PEWDIEPIE001',
        'assetCode': 'LOCAL1',
        'date': '2012-10-02 09:02:00'
      },
      {
        'machineCode': 'PEWDIEPIE003',
        'assetCode': 'LOCAL2',
        'date': '2012-10-02 09:02:00'
      }
    ];

const orderedByMonth = _.groupBy(this.rowData, function (item: any) {
      return item.date.substring(0, 7);
    });
    const groupedByYear = _.groupBy(orderedByMonth, function (item: any) {
      return item[0].date.substring(0, 4);
    });
```

[image]
thanks in advance

Comment: a bit more of a description would be helpful?

Comment: how to filter if date is 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in `lodash` called [`pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy)

```
var filteredByYear = _.pickBy(groupedByYear, function(value, key) {
  return key != '2019';
});
```

Since `groupBy` returns an `object`. This method `pickBy` works on objects based on key values and will filter `2019` out of the `object` you provided in screenshot.

## Update

Another method is [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter), which will return you only the values of filtered keys.

```
var filteredByYear = _.filter(groupedByYear, function(value, key) {
  return key != '2019';
});
```

Comment: what is the value of ```value```

Comment: how to filter ... year === 2019?

Comment: from your screenshot. since `2019` is the key the `value` is the `array` corresponding to `2019`. if you want to only keep `2019`, change the condition to `key === '2019'`, if you want to exclude `2019` the condition will be `key !== '2019'`

Comment: when key === '2019'. on console it display '2019': {...}
how to remove the ```2019``` when its already equal .